# Check for membership in a dict vs a set in python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, dictionary, set

Seems that checking the dict keys as set is a tad faster:

```
import random
import string
import timeit

repeat = 3
numbers = 1000

def time(statement, _setup=None):
    print min(
        timeit.Timer(statement, setup=_setup or setup).repeat(
            repeat, numbers))

random.seed('slartibartfast')

# Integers
length = 100000
d = {}
for _ in range(length):
    d[random.randint(0, 10000000)] = 0
s = set(d)

setup = """from __main__ import s, d, length
"""

time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in d')
time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in s')

# Strings
d = {}
for _ in range(length):
    d[''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for __ in range(16))] = 0
s = set(d)

test_strings= []
for _ in range(length):
    test_strings.append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for __ in range(16))

setup = """from __main__ import s, d, length, test_strings
"""

time('for i in test_strings: check = i in d')
time('for i in test_strings: check = i in s')
```

prints something like:

```
10.1242966769
9.73939713014
10.5156763102
10.2767765061
```

Is this to be expected or a random artifact ?

Wondering if it's worth while to create sets for dict keys in performance intensive code.

Edit: my measurements really made me wonder on underlying implementation, I am not trying to save microseconds, I am just curious - and yes if it turns out that underlying implementation really favors sets I could make a set of those dict keys - or not (I am actually patching legacy code).

Comment: If performance is so critical that differences of small fractions of a millisecond make a difference, Python is probably the wrong language to use. I would go for readability over saving 0.2 seconds per 100,000 iterations.

Comment: @John yes it's not so much a performance question per se - I became curious about the underlying implementation - are dict lookups implemented by sets ? Seems not

Comment: No they are no implemented by sets, but they use the same fundamental approach as sets. There is also no guarantee that this be the case, only that the big O constraints oh O(1) lookup hold under reasonable conditions.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D It is an interesting question. Without ever thinking about it very much, my hunch was that under the hood sets were dictionaries with null values, hence I would have guessed that lookup times would be virtually identical. It seems to be a little more complicated than that.

Comment: Edited with strings benchmark

Comment: @Pyrce - could you add some info on the implementation to your answer ?

Comment: You can add comments on the answer, but what do you mean add info on the implementation? All the code is there and it's just making random dicts/sets of varying sizes based on the `xrange` argument.

Comment: I mean the underlying cpython implementation of dicts and sets

Comment: Honestly that's a different question, and one you can look up (i.e. lmgtfy https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c -- https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c). The takeaway from my answer was "don't worry about the differences".

Comment: I never worried about the difference and it's not a different question it's what I am asking - see the comments above

Answer (score 3):

Honestly it depends heavily on hardware, OS, and data size/constraints. In general performance will be almost identical until you get really big data sizes. Note a few runs here where the `dict` does marginally better. At larger data structure sizes the internal implementation details start to dominate differences and on my machine `set` tends to perform significantly better.

The reality is under most situations the delta doesn't matter. If you really want better lookup performance consider moving to C level operations with `cython` or `ctypes`, or make use of library implementations designed for larger data sizes. Python base types are not meant for performance when reaching above a few million elements.

```
>>> # With empty dict as setup in question
>>> time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in d')
2.83035111427
>>> time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in s')
2.87069892883
>>> d = { random.random(): None for _ in xrange(100000) }
>>> s = set(d)
>>> time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in d')
3.84766697884
>>> time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in s')
3.97955989838
>>> d = { random.randint(0, 1000000000): None for _ in xrange(100000) }
>>> s = set(d)
>>> time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in d')
3.96871709824
>>> time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in s')
3.62110710144
>>> d = { random.randint(0, 1000000000): None for _ in xrange(10000000) }
>>> s = set(d)
>>> time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in d')
10.6934559345
>>> time('for i in xrange(length): check = i in s')
5.7491569519
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably depends on a variety of things. On my runs, dictionary lookups have been slightly faster, but not by enough to get excited about:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: d = {i: True for i in np.random.random(1000)}

In [3]: s = {i for i in np.random.random(1000)}

In [4]: checks = d.keys()[:500] + list(s)[:500]

In [5]: %timeit [k in d for k in checks]
10000 loops, best of 3: 83 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit [k in s for k in checks]
10000 loops, best of 3: 88.4 µs per loop

In [7]: d = {i: True for i in np.random.random(100000)}

In [8]: s = {i for i in np.random.random(100000)}

In [9]: checks = d.keys()[:5000] + list(s)[:5000]

In [10]: %timeit [k in d for k in checks]
1000 loops, best of 3: 865 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit [k in s for k in checks]
1000 loops, best of 3: 929 µs per loop
```